# How do I modify Image Map Pro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a plugin called Image Map Plus. What it does is high lights a hot spot on an image when I hover over that spot. What I would like it to do is this....

I have a list under the image. When I hover over one of the list items the corresponding hotspot on the image will get it's hover effect. The plug in provides that function but only on click not hover... by adding this to my list item

```html
<li><a href="#" data-open-spot="poly-3692">3314    Administration</a></li>
```

It has something do do with the data-open-spot="poly-3692"

The poly-3692 targets the hotspot. Here is the JS in my code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#map").imageMapPro({"id":4954,"editor":{"previewMode":1,"selected_hotspot":"poly-3692","tool":"poly"},"general":{"name":"dan","width":1143,"height":572,"responsive":1,"sticky_tooltips":0,"constrain_tooltips":1,"image_url":"http://test.ccri.edu/about/floorplans/knight/images/3rd_flr_2013_layout2.png","tooltip_animation":"grow","pageload_animation":"none"},"spots":[{"id":"poly-3692","type":"poly","x":12.876427829698859,"y":9.130122214234364,"width":5.919003115264798,"height":11.412652767792956,"actions":{"mouseover":"no-action","click":"no-action","link":"#","open_link_in_new_window":1},"default_style":{"opacity":1,"border_radius":50,"background_color":"#000000","background_opacity":0.4,"border_width":0,"border_style":"solid","border_color":"#ffffff","border_opacity":1,"fill":"#000000","fill_opacity":0,"stroke_color":"#ffffff","stroke_opacity":0.75,"stroke_width":0,"stroke_dasharray":"10 10","stroke_linecap":"round","use_icon":0,"icon_type":"library","icon_svg_path":"","icon_svg_viewbox":"","icon_fill":"#ffffff","icon_url":"","icon_is_pin":0,"icon_shadow":0},"mouseover_style":{"opacity":1,"border_radius":50,"background_color":"#ffffff","background_opacity":0.4,"border_width":0,"border_style":"solid","border_color":"#ffffff","border_opacity":1,"fill":"#4df936","fill_opacity":0.4,"stroke_color":"#ffffff","stroke_opacity":0.75,"stroke_width":0,"stroke_dasharray":"10 10","stroke_linecap":"round"},"tooltip_style":{"border_radius":5,"padding":20,"background_color":"#000000","background_opacity":0.9,"position":"top","width":300,"height":200,"auto_width":0,"auto_height":1},"text_style":{"title_color":"#ffffff","title_font_size":18,"title_font_family":"sans-serif","title_font_weight":700,"title_line_height":24,"text_color":"#aaaaaa","text_font_size":12,"text_font_family":"serif","text_font_weight":300,"text_line_height":16},"tooltip_content":{"title":"Lorem Ipsum","text":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas."},"points":[{"x":1.7543859649122806,"y":1.8181818181818181},{"x":100,"y":0},{"x":100,"y":98.18181818181819},{"x":22.807017543859647,"y":100},{"x":22.807017543859647,"y":89.0909090909091},{"x":0,"y":89.0909090909091},{"x":0,"y":47.27272727272727}],"vs":[[148.3644859813084,53.41121495327103],[214.8317757009346,52.22429906542056],[214.8317757009346,116.3177570093458],[162.60747663551402,117.50467289719626],[162.60747663551402,110.38317757009347],[147.17757009345794,110.38317757009347],[147.17757009345794,83.08411214953271]]}]});
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

And I found the "data-open-spot" in the linked JS file I just dot know how to modify it to work on hover instead of click here is the snippet.

```js
if (d || (e.unhighlightSpot(), e.hideTooltip()), e.visibleTooltip && "show-tooltip" == e.activeSpot.actions.mouseover && 1 == parseInt(e.settings.general.sticky_tooltips, 10)) {
                    var o = c.x - e.wrapOffsetLeft,
                        p = c.y - e.wrapOffsetTop,
                        q = 0,
                        r = 0;
                    e.updateTooltipPosition(e.visibleTooltip, e.visibleTooltipWidth, e.visibleTooltipHeight, o, p, q, r, 20)
                }
            }), e.wrap.find(".hs-hotspot-spot, .hs-hotspot-rect, .hs-hotspot-oval, .hs-poly-svg polygon").on("touchend", function(c) {
                var f = e.settings.spots[a(this).data("index")];
                return "follow-link" == f.actions.click && (1 == parseInt(f.actions.open_link_in_new_window) ? b.open(f.actions.link, "_blank") : b.location = f.actions.link), "show-tooltip" == f.actions.click && (e.hideTooltip(), e.activeSpotIndex != d && e.showTooltip(e.activeSpotIndex, 0, 0, !0)), !1
            }), e.wrap.on("touchend", function(b) {
                return (a(b.target).hasClass("hs-hotspot-container") || a(b.target).is("svg")) && (a(".hs-mouseover").removeClass("hs-mouseover"), e.unhighlightSpot(), e.hideTooltip()), !1
            }), a(c).on("click", "[data-open-spot]", function() {
                for (var b = a(this).data("open-spot"), c = 0; c < e.settings.spots.length; c++) {
                    var d = e.settings.spots[c];
                    d.id == b && (e.hideTooltip(), e.unhighlightSpot(), e.highlightSpot(c), ("show-tooltip" == d.actions.mouseover || "show-tooltip" == d.actions.click) && e.showTooltip(c, 0, 0, !0))
                }
            })
        },
        animateHotspotsLoop: function() {
            var a = this;
            if ("none" != a.settings.general.pageload_animation)
                for (var b = 750 / a.settings.spots.length, c = j(a.settings.spots.slice()), d = 0; d < c.length; d++) a.animateHotspot(c[d], b * d)
        },
        animateHotspot: function(b, c) {
            var d = this,
                e = a("#" + b.id);
            setTimeout(function() {
                "fade" == d.settings.general.pageload_animation && e.css({
                    opacity: b.default_style.opacity
                }), "grow" == d.settings.general.pageload_animation && e.css({
                    transform: "scale(1, 1)",
                    "-moz-transform": "scale(1, 1)",
                    "-webkit-transform": "scale(1, 1)"
                })
            }, c)
        },
        getEventCoordinates: function(a) {
            var b, c, d = this;
            return d.touch ? (b = a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX, c = a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) : (b = a.pageX, c = a.pageY), {
                x: b,
                y: c
            }
        },
```

you can see the data-open-spot about half way down. My JS is not very good so I'm not sure how to make the change but if anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I think you need to modify that to set `"sticky_tooltips": 1` under `general` and `"mouseover": "show-tooltip"` on the one object in the `spot` array in that giant configuration object you're passing to `map()`.

Comment: Hmmm Do you think you could copy/paste that into the code? I'm not sure the proper way to make those changes.

Comment: Is that configuration object hard-coded or are you getting it from a service? If it's hard-coded, you should just be able to text replace `"sticky_tooltips":0` with `"sticky_tooltips":1` and `"mouseover":"no-action"` with `"mouseover":"show-tooltip"` in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the call to imageMapPro with the changes from my comments (and also pretty-printed for my sanity):

```
$("#map").imageMapPro({  
   "id":4954,
   "editor":{  
      "previewMode":1,
      "selected_hotspot":"poly-3692",
      "tool":"poly"
   },
   "general":{  
      "name":"dan",
      "width":1143,
      "height":572,
      "responsive":1,
      "sticky_tooltips":1,
      "constrain_tooltips":1,
      "image_url":"http://test.ccri.edu/about/floorplans/knight/images/3rd_flr_2013_layout2.png",
      "tooltip_animation":"grow",
      "pageload_animation":"none"
   },
   "spots":[  
      {  
         "id":"poly-3692",
         "type":"poly",
         "x":12.876427829698859,
         "y":9.130122214234364,
         "width":5.919003115264798,
         "height":11.412652767792956,
         "actions":{  
            "mouseover":"show-tooltip",
            "click":"no-action",
            "link":"#",
            "open_link_in_new_window":1
         },
         "default_style":{  
            "opacity":1,
            "border_radius":50,
            "background_color":"#000000",
            "background_opacity":0.4,
            "border_width":0,
            "border_style":"solid",
            "border_color":"#ffffff",
            "border_opacity":1,
            "fill":"#000000",
            "fill_opacity":0,
            "stroke_color":"#ffffff",
            "stroke_opacity":0.75,
            "stroke_width":0,
            "stroke_dasharray":"10 10",
            "stroke_linecap":"round",
            "use_icon":0,
            "icon_type":"library",
            "icon_svg_path":"",
            "icon_svg_viewbox":"",
            "icon_fill":"#ffffff",
            "icon_url":"",
            "icon_is_pin":0,
            "icon_shadow":0
         },
         "mouseover_style":{  
            "opacity":1,
            "border_radius":50,
            "background_color":"#ffffff",
            "background_opacity":0.4,
            "border_width":0,
            "border_style":"solid",
            "border_color":"#ffffff",
            "border_opacity":1,
            "fill":"#4df936",
            "fill_opacity":0.4,
            "stroke_color":"#ffffff",
            "stroke_opacity":0.75,
            "stroke_width":0,
            "stroke_dasharray":"10 10",
            "stroke_linecap":"round"
         },
         "tooltip_style":{  
            "border_radius":5,
            "padding":20,
            "background_color":"#000000",
            "background_opacity":0.9,
            "position":"top",
            "width":300,
            "height":200,
            "auto_width":0,
            "auto_height":1
         },
         "text_style":{  
            "title_color":"#ffffff",
            "title_font_size":18,
            "title_font_family":"sans-serif",
            "title_font_weight":700,
            "title_line_height":24,
            "text_color":"#aaaaaa",
            "text_font_size":12,
            "text_font_family":"serif",
            "text_font_weight":300,
            "text_line_height":16
         },
         "tooltip_content":{  
            "title":"Lorem Ipsum",
            "text":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas."
         },
         "points":[  
            {  
               "x":1.7543859649122806,
               "y":1.8181818181818181
            },
            {  
               "x":100,
               "y":0
            },
            {  
               "x":100,
               "y":98.18181818181819
            },
            {  
               "x":22.807017543859647,
               "y":100
            },
            {  
               "x":22.807017543859647,
               "y":89.0909090909091
            },
            {  
               "x":0,
               "y":89.0909090909091
            },
            {  
               "x":0,
               "y":47.27272727272727
            }
         ],
         "vs":[  
            [  
               148.3644859813084,
               53.41121495327103
            ],
            [  
               214.8317757009346,
               52.22429906542056
            ],
            [  
               214.8317757009346,
               116.3177570093458
            ],
            [  
               162.60747663551402,
               117.50467289719626
            ],
            [  
               162.60747663551402,
               110.38317757009347
            ],
            [  
               147.17757009345794,
               110.38317757009347
            ],
            [  
               147.17757009345794,
               83.08411214953271
            ]
         ]
      }
   ]
});
```